# I changed wamp server to localhost:8008 because I am also running IIs. How do I change the address for phpmyadmin to same host?

Tags: apache, wamp

I changed the httpd.config file to listen on port 8008 because I have IIS running on port 80. Now, when I try to access phpmyadmin it tries to go to localhost/phpmyadmin instead of localhost:8008/phpmyadmin. How do I change the address to go to the correct one?

Comment: As stackoverflow is primarily for programming questions, you may get better responses to this kind of question on the https://serverfault.com/ stackexchange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1. navigate to your WAMP folder
2. Open wampmanager.tpl in your editor
3. Look for phpmyamin section 
4. Edit this line: localhost/phpmyadmin to this: localhost:8008/phpmyadmin/
5. Restart wamp
```